# How to set an attributes in departments to be between certain numbers?

Tags: java

I'm trying to set the attribute "Hour" to be between the numbers 0 and 23, How?
I'm trying to do it with a set function. So any answers to HOW?

public class Time {

```
private int Hour;
private int minute;
```

}//Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wish to use Math then you can add simple condition into your function.

```
private int hour;
private int minute;

public void setHour(int value) {
    if (value > 23) {
        value = 23;
    }
    if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
    }
    this.hour = value;
}

public void setMinute(int value) {
    if (value > 59) {
        value = 59;
    }
    if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
    }
    this.minute = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly. You want to guard the variables so they cannot be set to invalid values. So `Hour` should only be between 0 and 23, and `minute` between 0 and 59.

```
public class Time {
    private int Hour;
    private int minute;

    public int getHour() {
        return this.Hour;
    }
    
    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        // this.Hour = Math.min(Math.max(0, hour), 23);
        this.Hour = hour > 23 ? 23 : hour < 0 ? 0 : hour;
    }
    
    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        // this.minute = Math.min(Math.max(0, minute), 59);
        this.minute = minute > 59 ? 59 : minute < 0 ? 0 : minute;
    }
}
```

Comment: My direction is to do it without the "Math".